# Is it bad that one side of my armature has a different pole angle degree then the other?

Tags: rigging, armature

I don't think it's causing too much of an issue at the moment, I'm just not sure if the pole angle should be asymmetrical. On the left side of the armature, the pole angle is 9.1 degree's and the other is 180 degree's if it's readjusted then the mesh gets twisted. I won't be able to share the blend file but does anyone have any thoughts as to why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: It's normal for them to be opposites: 90 and -90, for example.  Your numbers are not normal.  You should look at your bone rolls.  Consider deleting half your armature and creating it via symmetrize operation instead, which is easier and more perfect than making both halves of a symmetrical armature by hand.

Comment: I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been intrigued by this Asymmetric Pole Angle Value behavior that works for months, as I have it on one of my characters.

Then, for some reason (that I found out relates to some degree to the Asymmetric Pole Angle issue), I started to have an even bigger, and critical issue on the same character, involving the Inverse Kinematics Bone Constraint for Leg Rig: where the Pole Target Knee Controller Bones were working but quite offset on Pose Mode, not only that: but the Deforming Knee Bone (as I had 3 Bones on the IK Chain for the Leg) and even it's Weight Painted Mesh on the Knee region was being twisted slightly sideways, by an unwanted Rotation of the Knee Bone's Y-Axis.

So, apparently, after much investigation, I've came up to the conclusion that both issues relate to the same thing: Alignement…Except that there are different categories of Alignment: Bones' Alignment (Body/Head/Tail) and Bone Rolls Alignement.

The smaller issue (*regarding Asymmetric Pole Angle Values*) relates only to **Bones' Bodies, Head and Tails Alignment** (X-Axis), *including* not only the Deforming Bones on the IK Chain, but also some or maybe even all of the Controller Bones on the IK Rig.

The bigger, critical issue (*regarding offset Pole Target Bone, Knee Bone & Knee Mesh twisting*) relates only to **Bones' Bone Rolls Alignment**, for Deforming Bones on the IK Chain; although it can be actually solved without Bone Rolls Alignment through IK Locks [Axis] (in this case, it would be the Bone Axis that is pointing forwards/backwards on the Leg, in principle, X or Z) at Inverse Kinematics Panel on Bone Properties Tab in Properties Editor, for one or more Bones on the IK Chain.

For the 1st case, the more the Bones Bodies/Heads/Tails are Unaligned, the larger would be the Asymmetric difference of Values between the 2 Pole Angles from each side.

You don't need to have any of those Alignments to have a good IK Bone Constraint to work properly, since for each case there are adequate workaround solutions I've already stated; but I'll remember the one for Asymmetric Pole Targets: they are just annoying to deal with, but rather easy to find the exact 'matching' Values for the actual orientation of Bone & Mesh. They still indicate Unaligned Bodies/Heads/Tails of the Bones involved (remember, for both Deforming and Controller Bones for the IK Rig).